# How do I connect my files from Windows 7 laptop to my Raspbian Raspberry Pi 2 (using LAN)?

Tags: windows-7, raspbian, raspberry-pi2, lan

I have recently bought a Raspberry Pi 2. I am using it to test some python socket server games that I made, but it takes me ages to put the client's .py file on my memory stick, then put it on my Pi every time I update the code. I would like an easy way to connect the two's files, preferably using LAN. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your classic network cable to access Raspberry Pi (eg. SSH) without Internet Connection.

[Follow this useful guide.](https://pihw.wordpress.com/guides/direct-network-connection/)

Comment: Thanks for the help :)